# nginx redirect domain a to b with parameters and sub domain

Tags: nginx, redirect

How would i redirect

```
https://aaa.com                     > https://bbb.com
http://aaa.com                      > http://bbb.com
https://sub.aaa.com                 > https://sub.bbb.com
https://aaa.com/foo/bar?baz=buzz    > https://bbb.com/foo/bar?baz=buzz
```

basically just change the domain name and preserve everything else including subdomain,
a 301 redirect
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to extract the subdomain. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;

    server_name ~^(?<sub>.*\.)?aaa\.com$;

    return 301 $scheme://${sub}bbb.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Ok, had to play with it a little, but I got it to work
`server_name ~^(?<sub>.*\.)?aaa\.com$;`